# Is there a better way to declare an object which should be used in onNext() and onCompleted()?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have the following method:

```
@Override
    public void loadMovieDetails(@NonNull String slugId) {
        view.showLoadingIndicator(true);
        final Movie[] movie = new Movie[1];

        view.showLoadingIndicator(true);

        mCompositeDisposable.add(MovieAPIFactory.getInstance().getAPIService().getExtendedInfo(slugId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        //onNext
                        movieRes -> movie[0] = movieRes,
                        //onError
                        throwable -> {
                            view.showEmptyState(true);
                            view.onMovieDetailsFailed();
                        },
                        //onCompleted
                        ()->{
                            view.showLoadingIndicator(false);
                            view.showEmptyState(false);
                            view.onMovieDetailsLoaded(movie[0]);
                        }
                ));


    }
```

As you can see, `movie` is used in `onNext` and `onSubscribe`. I wanted to devlare ot in `subscribe` body, but there's no opportunity to do it, so I have to convert it to array and after work with this array. But I don't think that it's the best way, so, can you help me to find a solution, which would be more preferable in such case?

Comment: Not sure why you need to put it inside an array? Isn't declaring the movie "final" enough?

Comment: @JClassic, when I change line in the following way: `final Movie movie = null;`, studio underlines line `movieRes -> movie = movieRes` and writes that Cannot assign a value to final variable 'movie'. Or I understood your solution in a wrong way?

Comment: Oh sorry didn't notice you were reassigning it. my bad

Comment: @JClassic, it's ok

Comment: Do your api emit multiple results?. If it is a rest api it would emit only one response per request, in that case you can use a single instead of observable, or simply neglect onComplete